# CSS Table Border Does not Collapse

Tags: css

I have a table like this and I am adding the border-bottom. There is space between the columns. I cannot figure where I did wrong. What should I do here?

[image]

```
#T_e5208500_98ac_11e7_a588_1866da2de39f table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}        
#T_e5208500_98ac_11e7_a588_1866da2de39f th,td {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 67px;
}        
#T_e5208500_98ac_11e7_a588_1866da2de39f th {
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}      
#T_e5208500_98ac_11e7_a588_1866da2de39f td {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: We need a [mcve]

Comment: please  add  full code with html and  explain in detail your  issue

Answer (score 1):

You can try including below lines in your CSS code

```
table{
border-spacing : 0;
}
```

[Sample Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhannur/fmyu67cL/)

Answer (score 0):

try this snippet:

```
#T_e5208500_98ac_11e7_a588_1866da2de39f table,th,td{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was missing some HTML but here is a simple solution

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello Header</td>
        <td>Hello Header</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the css

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

th,td {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
thead{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```